# How to set heap size for wildfly inside Docker container?

Tags: java, docker, jvm, containers, wildfly

I am trying to increase heap size for wildfly in docker container. This is easily done by updating `wildfly/bin/standalone.conf` in a regular wildfly setup.

Our base docker image for wildfly has a default heapsize of `512 MB` which is required to be `1GB` in one of the web apps. One way to go is by simple text replace in the Docker file using `sed` command -

```
RUN sed -i -- 's/JAVA_OPTS="-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m/JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx6144m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m/g' /path/standalone.conf
```

I wanted to know if there's another (cleaner) way to solve this?

Answer (score 10):

When using `docker-compose` set environment variable as follows!

```
environment:
  - JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

do not use `"` (quotes)!

Comment: java.net.preferIPv4Stack is repeated twice

Answer (score 9):

You can pass the value of the JAVA_OPTS environment variable in the command used to run the docker container:

```
docker run -it --env JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms2048m -Xmx6144m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true" jboss/wildfly
```

Alternatively, you can extend the standard image by creating a `Dockerfile` containing:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:latest

COPY standalone.conf $JBOSS_HOME/bin/
```

and placing your modified standalone.conf in the directory next to it.

Then you can build it:

```
docker build -t my/wildfly:latest .
```

and run it:

```
docker run my/wildfly
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS rather than JAVA_OPTS .Because JVM directly understand JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself, but there is now (at least WF26) a variable `JBOSS_JAVA_SIZING` in `standalone.conf`, used as a subpart of `JAVA_OPTS`.

```
if [ "x$JBOSS_JAVA_SIZING" = "x" ]; then
   JBOSS_JAVA_SIZING="-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"
fi
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
    JAVA_OPTS="$JBOSS_JAVA_SIZING -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
...
```

So you should be able to rewrite it through docker environment variables.