# How add JAVA_OPTS variable to wildfly by kuberentes yaml file?

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, wildfly

I'm trying to add new variable to JAVA_OPTS

Wildfly command in Dockerfile:

```
CMD cd /opt/wildfly/bin && ./standalone.sh -b="0.0.0.0"
```

Pod yaml file:

```
 env:
   - name: JAVA_OPTS
     value: -DattributeName=value
```

But the new attribute is not added to system properties and I see only default variables defined in standalone.conf:

```
JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms6g -Xmx6g -XX:MetaspaceSize=1536M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1536M -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8 -Ddefault.client.encoding=UTF-8 -Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING=UTF-8 -Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING=true -Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=6000 -Didit.system.placeholder
```

Any idea how set JAVA_OPTS by k8s yaml file? Thanks!

Comment: Have your tried the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221742/how-to-set-heap-size-for-wildfly-inside-docker-container ?

Comment: Which Image are you based on ?

Comment: @AlfredoPalhares this is Wildfly image based on java

Comment: @Kris.J in this question the JAVA_OPTS added by docker command and I want inject the value by pod yaml

Comment: @Mortova, sure but pod env definition is still an environment variable thats being exposed within the container for the consuming app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I extended the standard wildfly image by creating a `Dockerfile` containing:

```
COPY standalone.conf /opt/wildfly/bin
```

I added placeholder in `standalone.conf` for JAVA_OPTS added by kubernetes environment variable

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS $DYNAMIC_JAVA_OPTS"
```

Inject the parameter by k8s yaml

```
env:
   - name: DYNAMIC_JAVA_OPTS
   value: -DattributeName=value
```